# Live txt field send without button

Tags: android, button

I'm trying to use a toggle button to switch between English -> Morse code and Morse code -> English. At this moment, I have to press the toggle button everytime I want the inputted data to be converted and this is not good. I want the toggle button only to be pressed once as desired to select to what it wants to translate to, and then while the user inputs data into the txt field, it will translate it as the user inputs data. Is this possible? And will this cause the app to lag?

If this will lag I'd like something else then.
A switch like the toggle button, to again choose to which one it needs to translate to. And then use to button to convert. This is somewhat possible now, but I need to click on the toggle button to translate, while I want to select the convert button to translate, and the toggle button to choose between English -> Morse code and Morse code -> English.

Here is some code I have for the toggle button:

```
final ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleEnMo_Button);
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    // to English
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toggle.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (edit_convert.getText().length() != 0) {
                        morseCode.setEnInput(edit_convert.getText().toString());
                        String txtToEnglish = morseCode.getEnInput();

                        morseCode.setMorseInput(morseCode.toEnglish(txtToEnglish));
                        String txtToMorse = morseCode.getMorseInput();

                        txtEnglish.setText(txtToEnglish);
                        txtMorse.setText(txtToMorse);
                    } else {
                        txtEnglish.setText("Text field empty");
                    }
                } else {
                    // to Morse
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toggle.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (edit_convert.getText().length() != 0) {
                        morseCode.setEnInput(edit_convert.getText().toString());
                        String txtToEnglish = morseCode.getEnInput();

                        morseCode.setMorseInput(morseCode.toMorse(txtToEnglish));
                        String txtToMorse = morseCode.getMorseInput();

                        txtEnglish.setText(txtToEnglish);
                        txtMorse.setText(txtToMorse);
                    } else {
                        txtEnglish.setText("Text field empty");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

And the code I use for radio buttons and convert button which works:

```
button_convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // show radio button text
        int selectId = radioMorseGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioMorseButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectId);
        if (selectId == R.id.toEnglish) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    radioMorseButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // to english
            if (edit_convert.getText().length() != 0) {
                morseCode.setEnInput(edit_convert.getText().toString());
                String txtToEnglish = morseCode.getEnInput();

                morseCode.setMorseInput(morseCode.toEnglish(txtToEnglish));
                String txtToMorse = morseCode.getMorseInput();

                txtEnglish.setText(txtToEnglish);
                txtMorse.setText(txtToMorse);
            } else {
                txtEnglish.setText("Text field empty");
            }
        } else if (selectId == R.id.toMorse) {
            // to morse
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    radioMorseButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (edit_convert.getText().length() != 0) {
                morseCode.setEnInput(edit_convert.getText().toString());
                String txtToEnglish = morseCode.getEnInput();

                morseCode.setMorseInput(morseCode.toMorse(txtToEnglish));
                String txtToMorse = morseCode.getMorseInput();

                txtEnglish.setText(txtToEnglish);
                txtMorse.setText(txtToMorse);
            } else {
                txtEnglish.setText("Text field empty");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are asking about intercepting user input as they type into a text field. You can use a [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). Here's some sample code that demonstrates this.

```
  EditText mInputEt;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      ...
      mInputEt.addTextChangedListener(mMyTextWatcher);

  }

  private TextWatcher mMyTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           //take user input here and do something with it, like your translations
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
```

Now to your question regarding lag, it shouldn't lag as long as all your intensive operations are executed in the background, off the main thread.

Comment: That looks interesting. I will try it out tomorrow and see if I can use that.